# Trying to resize a UITableView glitches the screen for a second before displaying properly

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview, uinavigationbar

I had a lot of trouble resizing a UITableView to fit between an UINavigationBar and a UITabBar. My implementation involved creating a custom frame in viewDidAppear(), and then setting the UITableView to an appropriate frame. Although this solution works well, it doesn't work perfectly- the screen has a little spasm every time the view is loaded. I figured the issue was due to the UITableViewb becoming fullscreen, as it wants to, and then me resizing it, in front of the user's eyes. However, I have no idea how else to implement what I want to: resizing the UITableView to fit into the screen properly. Here's my implementation in viewDidAppear():

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.view.superview addSubview:navigationBar];

    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.origin.y + 44;
    self.tableView.frame = frame;

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

It's very hard to see the effect when recorded on video, and probably terrible in GIF form, but [here's a little GIF](http://gifninja.com/animatedgifs/107243/uitableview-glitch.gif) I recorded of the flash being induced.

Here is the result if I use that same code in viewWillAppear() instead:
[image: result]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem, turned out it was an issue with auto layout on the view. In the Interface Builder, switch to the File Inspector property view and make sure 'Use Autolayout' is unchecked.

After this, you can consistently resize your UITableView in the viewWillAppear method without the glitches.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   CGRect frame = [tableView frame];    
   frame.size.height = 365; 
   self.tableView.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Although this problem (and the project itself) is no longer around, this definitely appears to have been the cause, and I'm glad the solution was found after all this time. I'm sure others will run into this someday in the future, as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why using `viewDidAppear`, by the time this method gets called your view is visible on screen then you will of course receive a glitch.

What you have to do is change the method from `viewDidAppear` to `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I use viewWillAppear(), the UITableView doesn't even show it's face, and the UINavigationBar takes up the entire screen. If I decide to not include the NavigationBar, then the UITableView either is fullscreen, or doesn't show up. I mentioned above that I haven't found a way to use viewWillApear() like I'm using viewDidAppear().